# To see if a system behaves chaotically does one have to vary (in a tiny way) the initial momenta of ALL constituents of the system?

Tags: chaos-theory

Consider a deterministic system (a gas, a liquid, or a solid, each of which can have an arbitrary form; for example, the atmosphere, a waterfall, or a double pendulum) which consists of a huge number of constituents like atoms or molecules, which have a certain distribution of their momenta.

To see if the system behaves chaotically do we have to vary the momenta of **all** its constituents in a tiny (and in the same) way to see if the system behavior is chaotic, or can we just vary the momenta of a tiny portion of the system?

I ask this because in an answer to a question I read that varying a little piece of the weather system would imply that the weather system is a chaotic phenomenon (which it obviously is).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. One certainly doesn't have to vary a huge number of system variables to test for divergence of trajectories (i.e., the sensitivity to initial conditions characteristic of chaos) - changing a single one is sufficient.

That's what justifies the famous hyperbole "Does the flap of a butterfly's wing in Brazil set off a tornado in Texas?", already covered in Physics SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/231909/75633) - whose answer, by the way, is "Well, yes, but it can also prevent the tornado or have a completely different effect (including nothing remarkable), just like every one of the innumerable arbitrarily small perturbations the system is constantly subjected to.".

Comment: And what about a double pendulum or a waterfall?

Comment: @descheleschilder It's the same for the double pendulum. A chaotic system is sensitive to arbitrary perturbations in the state space, which typically includes perturbations along a single of its axes (corresponding to a given system variable). As for the waterfall, do you mean a chaotic [waterwheel](http://www.ace.gatech.edu/experiments2/2413/lorenz/fall02/)? Otherwise I don't know any chaotic waterfall model.

Comment: So in the double pendulum, you let a very small part of the momenta of the atoms which make the DP up (with respect to the weather system, a very, very, very small part of all atoms which make up the pendulum) vary in a tiny way (atoms which, as said only form a very tiny part of the DP)?  By a waterfall I mean a stream of water that starts somewhere on a high level and streams down to a lower level, meeting stones, obstacles, etc. on its way. I know it's not a real waterfall, but more a stream of water going downwards on a rough surface.

Comment: Atoms aren't part of the usual model for the double pendulum, but yes, nearby trajectories diverge exponentially fast, so no matter how tiny the initial separation - including one of, say, $10^{-22}$ - one will observe them diverge eventually. I don't know any specific model for a waterfall off the top of my head, but what you describe should admit some chaotic models, perhaps even some displaying spatial-temporal chaos, pattern formation, etc.

Comment: Do you think that that the motion of a double pendulum will change if you make a little variation in the momentum of **one** atom out of **all**  the atoms that constitute the double pendulum?

Comment: Likewise, do you really think that the total weather system (in which there are no critical regions) will change if one varies a virtually infinite part of it? Look at films of tornadoes and the enormous destruction they cause. How can this be connected to a butterfly that varies this infinite part in a slightly different way (w.r.t. the total weather system)? If so, **how**?

Comment: "Do you think [...]" @descheleschilder It's not a matter of opinion. Some systems can be shown to be chaotic, which means that typical, *arbitrarily small* perturbations put them on new trajectories that are eventually totally different from the unperturbed one. And 'totally different' doesn't mean with more or fewer extreme events - they might just happen at different times, for instance. As for the butterfly wing flap, I believe David Hammen has [answered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/231909/75633) you rather well already, back in 2016. :)

Comment: I don't mean with "do you think..." that it is a matter of opinion. The small perturbations are put on the **whole** system, after which the whole system might diverge or not. In trying to show if a double pendulum behaves chaotically one does not put a small change on just **one** atom but on **all** atoms of the dp at once, after which the dp will after a certain time behave in a completely different way than if the small perturbations weren't put on the **all** atoms. Macroscopically this translates itself in small variations of the arms of the dp  (the **whole** dp) and see what happens.

Comment: @descheleschilder I mentioned it before, but let me emphasize: the usual equations for the double pendulum don't refer to atoms at all. It's a rigid-body or point-mass model so, strictly speaking, asking about changes on one atom is simply an ill-posed question. I've interpreted it so far as meaning an extremely minute change - if you do literally mean an atom, then you need to use a different description for the pendulum, one that includes its atoms.